# NA in-between values --> False Correlations and Plots?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a problem regarding predicting values based on a model under the condition that the values have NA in-between (see code below as an example). 
As you can see in the plot, the predicted line seems odd and my assumption is:  the NA's are kinda "ignored".. Do you perhaps have a solution for this issue?

I'm also running a model through a loop for other value vectors and on their way on looping the correlations between values and predicted values some error messages like "incompatible error" and "invalid factor level, NA generated" appears. So I need a way to ignore the NA in-between...

```
scale <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
values <- c(2, NA, NA, NA, 30, 45, 60, 75, 85, 100)
mod <- nls(values~(scale)^a, start=list(a=1))
summary(mod)
cor(values, c(predict(mod)))  

plot(scale,values,pch=16)
lines(scale, c(predict(mod),NA,NA,NA), col='blue',lty=2, lwd=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good to read the manual page(s) for the functions you are using. The handling of missing data is controlled by several arguments. First, your `cor()` function should have produced an error message since the default behavior in `nls()` is to delete observations with missing values so the length of `scale` and `predict(mod)` is different because three values were eliminated as containing missing values. Then you tack those missing values to the end of `predict(mod)`, but the missing values are not at the end of `values` which makes your plot misleading. Try this:

```
mod <- nls(values~(scale)^a, start=list(a=1), na.action="na.exclude")
cor(values, c(predict(mod)), use="complete.obs")
# [1] 0.9900571
plot(scale, values, pch=16)
lines(scale, predict(mod), col='blue',lty=2, lwd=3)
```

Now the plot is not misleading at all.
[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you are wanting your plot to look like, but this is an example that plots the line over the points.

```r
plot(scale,values,pch=16)
lines(scale[!is.na(values)], predict(mod), col='blue',lty=2, lwd=3)
```

[image]

As for your second question you should create a separate post for it, and include a more complete example of your code, including the loop.